# Позиционирование echo

Tags: php, позиционирование, echo

На сайте стоит PHP форма обратной связи, где есть строка:

```
    if ($result){
    echo "Сообщение отправлено";
```

после отправки данное оповещение выводится в конце сайта в "подвале", где и написан сам PHP-код, но нужно чтобы эта строка выводилась под самой формой обратной связи. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Переместить проверку в форму обратной связи есть возможность?

Comment: Нет такой возможности

Comment: Если не сложно выведите пожалуйста код, формирующий форму, за что там можно зацепиться?

Comment: <form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
  <p>Name:</p>
   <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Enter your name" x-autocompletetype="name" title="Enter your name">
  <p>Email:</p>
   <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter your email" x-autocompletetype="email" title="Enter your email">
  <p>Message:</p>
   <textarea name="message" required rows="5" id="message" title="Enter your message"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" type="button" value="SEND">
   </form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой и очевидный ответ - вставить код отправки письма в начало страницы, где ему и место (обычно, вся логика стремится к началу страницы, чтобы к моменту вывода на страницу были получены все необходимые данные). Там же формировать сообщение, примерно так

```
$message = '';

if ($result)
    $message = "Сообщение отправлено";
```

И потом выводить его в нужном месте

```
echo $message;
```

Есть еще костыльный вариант выводить сообщение в скрытом блоке и с помощью javascript перемещать его в место назначения и делать видимым.

Comment: Дело в том, что `$message = ' ';` уже используется в самом коде таким образом: `$message = 'Name: '.$_POST['name'].'; Email: '.$_POST['email'].'; Message: '.$_POST['message'].';';`

Comment: @vladislav_zp ну назовите по-другому переменную, в чем проблема)

Comment: теперь вообще на экран ничего не выводится..

Comment: "теперь" - это когда?) может быть, поделитесь, что вы попробовали сделать?

Comment: изменил название переменной: $displaymessage = '';

if ($result)
    $displaymessage = "Сообщение отправлено"; ///////////////////// а под кнопкой отправить вставил  <?php echo $displaymessage; ?>

Comment: @vladislav_zp да, все верно сделали. А вот код обработки письма вы тоже перенесли вверх? $result у вас до условия определяется? Замените $result в условии на 1 и посмотрите. появится ли сообщение. Если появится - значит $result у вас не определен к моменту проверки. В идеале - покажите код этого файла, избавленный от лишнего.

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое! Можно еще вопрос, как сделать чтобы страница не обновлялась? Много гуглил, разные примеры пробовал, никак не получается, всё равно после отправки формы сайт обновляется..:(

Comment: @vladislav_zp ajax гуглите